# Parmi les deux formes citées dans le corps de la question (deux exemples) , laquelle respecte les conventions grammaticales?

Tags: pronoms, pronom-de-reprise

Exemple 1:

> A) J’ai regardé le film « Donjons et Dragons » récemment et j’ai bien apprécié. Je me demande si je pourrais trouver mon bonheur dans le jeu qui **y** est associé.

> B) J’ai regardé le film « Donjons et Dragons » récemment et j’ai bien
> apprécié. Je me demande si je pourrais trouver mon bonheur dans le jeu qui **lui** est associé.

Exemple 2:

> C) Cette démonstration de l'identité d'Euler est effectivement relativement simple et permet de comprendre comment cette équation est liée à l'exponentielle complexe et à l'équation différentielle qui **y** est associée.

> D) Cette démonstration de l'identité d'Euler est effectivement relativement simple et permet de comprendre comment cette équation est liée à l'exponentielle complexe et à l'équation différentielle qui **lui** est associée.

Je me retrouve souvent face à des phrases où le pronom « lui » est employé pour faire référence à des objets inanimés ou à des concepts abstraits. Toutefois, selon de nombreuses sources que j'ai consultées, son usage devrait être réservé exclusivement aux êtres humains ou aux animaux de compagnie. Pourriez-vous m'éclairer davantage sur cette question?

Comment: Il semble que tu sois tombé uniquement sur des grammaires prescriptives. En bref,  dans la GGF: « Lui: Le plus souvent, l'antécédent est humain, mais il peut aussi être non humain ». Pour comprendre détail et historique : [Histoire d'une norme, emploi des pronoms « lui », « eux », « elle(s) », « en », « y »](https://www.persee.fr/doc/lfr_0023-8368_1972_num_16_1_5705). Extrait : «  [cette norme]  prend, selon les auteurs, une forme plus ou moins stricte : pour les uns, c'est une règle qui souffre des exceptions, pour les autres ne pas la respecter c'est tomber dans un parler négligé. »

Comment: Est-il possible de les utiliser de manière interchangeable sans risquer d'être repris et corrigé par un correcteur extrêmement rigoureux?

Comment: Je ne me risquerais pas à donner une réponse. Tout dépend de quel correcteur et de quel examen, et il y a des gens braqués sur une langue immuable à tous les niveaux.

Comment: @None Je te remercie None pour tes commentaires. Dans les contextes spécifiques que j’ai évoqués, impliquant l’utilisation des pronoms « lui » et « y », le bon usage ou les puristes voudraient qu’on emploie lequel des deux? Et toi, est-ce que tu opterais naturellement pour « lui » ou pour « y »?

Comment: Moi je dis lui spontanément sans y réfléchir (même à l'écrit) et je n'ai que faire des puristes qui me reprendraient.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec None. Moi je ne bronche pas quand pas quand j'entends l'un ou l'autre, pas de différence. Sans doute parce que de toute façon, les sonorités des deux sont assez proches, au delà de la grammaire.

Answer (score 4):

***Lui*** n'est pas réservé ici aux êtres vivants. Dans les deux phrases, je préférerais ***lui*** mais ***y*** est aussi possible.

- *qui est associé à quelque chose/à quelqu'un* → *qui ***lui*** est associé*.
- *qui est associé à quelque chose/quelque part* → *qui ***y*** est associé*.

S'il fallait trouver une nuance, je dirais qu'***y*** suggère aussi parfois le lieu où l'association est réalisée (qui est associé ***où*** ?) alors que ***lui*** ne représente que le complément d'objet indirect (qui est associé ***à quoi/à qui*** ?).

Comment: Les sonorités des deux sont suffisamment similaires pour que le passage de l'un à l'autre soit facile. Probablement le genre de situation où la langue évolue vite.